# Discord bot commands stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The codes commands below all of a sudden stopped working. In pycharm I don't get any errors, and my on_message event already has the `await bot.process_commands(message)` under it.

You'll see there are `try:` and `except:` statements, I added those and *they do* fail and send those error messages.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def report(ctx, user, reason):
    try:
        if ctx.channel.id == 730496513255669881:
        # player DM side
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Your Guild Report has Been Submitted!", color=0xb92d5d)
            embed.add_field(name="You Reported: " + user, value="Report Reason: " + reason, inline=True)
            embed.set_footer(text="You will be contacted about your report within 1 to 2 days")
            await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("Uh oh!")

# report command errors
@report.error
async def report_error(ctx, error):
    try:
        if ctx.channel.id == 730496513255669881:
            if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
                if error.param.name == 'user' or 'reason':
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Insufficient Arguments!", color=0xb92d5d)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Please use !report (player/user) (reason)")
                    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
                    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
            if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Your on a Cooldown!", color=0xb92d5d)
                embed.set_footer(text="There is a 1 day cooldown for using this command, and it isn't over yet")
                await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
                await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    except:
        await ctx.channel.send("Umm error...")
```

Is there any way I can somehow print an error message?
Or do you have any suggestions for what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

So I went into my privacy settings, and I turned server member DMs off.
Fixed the problem.

**How to get errors from failed commands:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, exc):
    etype = type(exc)
    trace = exc.__traceback__
    verbosity = 4
    lines = traceback.format_exception(etype, exc, trace, verbosity)

    traceback_text = ''.join(lines)
    await ctx.channel.send(traceback_text)
```